# Steps in exploratory methods for mild-sized data with mixed categorical and numerical values?

Tags: data-mining, categorical-data, linear-regression, numerical

Experienced in signal/image analysis, and new to data science, I recently was challenged with a relatively simple dataset: 100 to 200 items, about 10-20 numerical variables (in the [0-1] or percentage range), with only one variable used at present time for ranking, and 5 to 10 categorical variables, each with few options. A categorical variable takes about 2 to 4 different values.

I would like first to get insight on potential structures in such data. I have browsed Agresti's [Analysis of Ordinal Categorical Data](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470082895,subjectCd-STZ0.html), some have advised me to invest on TDA ([Topological data Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_data_analysis)). Yet I do not know where to start from.

Do you have guidelines, best practices on such REAL data to gradually address the aforementioned issues, from visualization to genuine processing/inference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a reasonably good approximation of steps for *exploratory data analysis (EDA)* by reviewing the [EDA section](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/eda.htm) of the *NIST Engineering Statistics Handbook*. Additionally, you might find helpful parts of [my related answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/1006/2452) here on *Data Science SE*.

Methods, related to EDA, are too diverse that it is not feasible to discuss them in a single answer. I will just mention several approaches. If you are interested in applying *classification* to your data set, you might find information, mentioned in [my other answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/135842/31372) helpful. In order to *detect structures* in a data set, you can try to apply [principal component analysis (PCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). If, on the other hand, you are interested in exploring *latent structures* in data, consider using [exploratory factor analysis (EFA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_factor_analysis).

Comment: I appreciate your global-to-local answer with keywords, and especially the reference to the [NIST/SEMATECH e-Handbook of Statistical Methods](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/) which was in my reference base; but forgotten

Comment: @LaurentDuval: You are very welcome.